# Deleting contact from address book

Tags: iphone

Hi all i am using ABNewPersonViewController in my app.Using this controller i dont want to add contact to iPhone contacts book.When user clicks on save i just want to import values from the ABNewPersonViewController,not to save the addressbook of iPhone.I do no how to avoid adding this record to addressBook of iphone.

Answer (score 2):

`ABNewPersonViewController` has a read/write property on it, "`addressBook`", that determines to what address book newly-created contacts are added.  What I would do in this situation is to create a temporary `ABAddressBookRef`, create the view controller, set the view controller's addressBook property to my temporary `ABAddressBookRef`, and then later get the data I need from the temporary `ABAddressBookRef` and then dispose of the temporary addressBook appropriately.